# How to join results from with operator in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I use query builder for execution inquiries to db like as:

```
$result = Order::with("product", "images");
```

As  result I get response with two nested objects inside:

```
{["product" : [{}], "images" : [{}]]}
```

How can I join these two objects to one, that to get the following response:

```
{"title" : "Product name", "price" : 3, "images" :{}, "order" : {} }
```

Comment: what is the relation between Order and product, images? Also, are you sure there is a relation between order and images and not product and images?

Comment: Relations between `Order` and `Product` is: `Order.product_id = Product.id`  and `Product.image = images.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) here:

```
Order::with('products.images')->first();
```

If you want to get an array or JSON instead of collection, use `toArray()` or `toJson()` methods on collection.

Comment: You have to remove the first `products`, because `products.images` will load `products`.

Comment: In this case you will get object products and inside object images. But I need join this in one object product

Comment: @Hamama did you try to use `toArray()` or `toJson()` as I suggested?